# Generating power in zero-g

Tags: design, microgravity, power, heat

When generating electricity, energy is lost to friction in mechanical bearings (e.g. turbine or generator bearings) and as heat, through resistance in transmission wires.

If you were generating electricity in a low gravity environment, could the power station be designed to make use of the low gravity environment to reduce the above losses?

(This is not a perpetual motion question.)

Comment: What sort of power generation are you thinking about? [Electric generators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_generator)?

Comment: As far as I know, friction does not really apply when talking about gravity's effect on electricity. If you're in a microgravity environment, batteries and energy storage devices Funktion the same whether you're in deep space or low earth orbit

Comment: I guess my question is, how much does earths gravity effect the rpm of an electric generator?

Comment: @Dragongeek many/most/all electricity generation sources on Earth involve big heavy things that rotate. Hydropower, Coal/Gas, as well as kinetic storage devices all have spinning things that convert flow to rotation which then is converted to AC power. There is certainly some friction in the bearings (mechanical, magnetic, etc.) supporting the weight of these against gravity. It may not be significant compared to other inefficiencies, but it's there.

Comment: @S.Medina I think this is an interesting question! In addition to friction associated with bearings used to support the weight of rotating things against Earth's gravity, there is friction due to the air. This is particularly a problem when energy is temporarily stored in high speed rotating masses (instead of chemical batteries) as backup power or makeup power. I think with a little editing this question will be reopened. It's very possible someone with more experience here in SE will edit it for you to speed things up.

Comment: Thank you uhoh. That is pretty much what I was looking for. So basically you would save fuel. It's just such a small percentage that it’s not even noticeable right? Also I apologize, I’m terrible at articulation and this is my first question posted. Had to pick six categories and my points weren’t high enough to get the ones I wanted.

Comment: While 0g would be beneficial to all forms that don't *depend* on gravity (convective transfer of media like steam rising/separating from boiling water, or the aforementioned hydroelectric, where gravity is the source of energy) I wouldn't be so sure about air drag. It's a tiny factor in some cases, but cold welding is a headache several orders of magnitude worse. And cooling! Our 1g provides us with 1bar of vastly abundant coolant - air. In space you're stuck with emissive radiators.

Comment: OTOH that coolant deprives us of at least 2/3 of solar energy half of the time, and the source of 1g deprives us of 100% of it the other half of the time. "Night" is just us entering solar eclipse caused by our (immediate) proximity to Earth. Move far away from Earth and there's no nighttime. So, we have a ballpark of 12 times the efficiency of solar panels.

Comment: @S.Medina I'm not sure what "Had to pick six categories and my points weren’t high enough..." means. by the way there is also a chat room for this site that's open for discussion/advice/suggestions, etc. Just find Chat at the bottom of the page. If you can edit your question (click edit) and make some changes based on comments and your responses here, that's better than leaving the clarification only in the comments. Welcome to Stack Exchange by the way!

Comment: @S.Medina:  "So basically you would save fuel. It's just such a small percentage that it’s not even noticeable right?" - No. The percentage would be noticeable. But getting things into space and adapting to operation in its conditions is ludicrously expensive - the savings would never come close to recuperating the cost of getting the power plant there in the first place.

Comment: Why should a solution using mechanically moving or rotating parts be used? Solar cells or Radioisotope thermoelectric generators did work successful for decades. Fuel cells were used for Apollo and the Shuttle.

Comment: @Uwe: Solar cells don't work at night, and reusable storage of large amounts of energy is a difficult problem, especially when you are unable to build a dam to hold a couple cubic kilometers of water pumping it up during the day and pushing through turbines at night. RTGs have a lousy efficiency comparing to the price tag. Fuel cells require fuel, which you need to manufacture somehow. Probably nuclear reactors are the best large-scale option for space - and they do have moving parts.

Answer (score 3):

Low or zero G makes it easier to use [magnetic bearings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_bearing), which eliminate friction losses from conventional bearings.

Gravity doesn't really impact the rotational speed of a generator: the energy spent on the upward half of the rotation (moving mass up) is compensated by the downward half.

Low gravity doesn't help with transmission losses. In outer space (depending on where you are, Earth orbit is too hot for this), you may be in an environment where you can use [superconductors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-temperature_superconductivity) without active cooling, and that would eliminate the transmission losses.

Comment: Note: you'd need to be in permanent shadow and have any non-superconducting parts of your generator totally insulated for it to work.